# Hibernate DLL validate for custom @ForeignKey annotation seems to fail?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, flyway, hibernate-validator

I am having an issue with Hibernate validating Schema against a Flyway initial migration script.

The entity failing in question:

```java
@Entity
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "agent_descriptions")
public class AgentDescriptions {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "short_description", length = 512)
    private String shortDescription;

    @Column(name = "long_description", length = 2048)
    private String longDescription;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_agent_id",value = ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT))
    private Agent agent;
}
```

The Flyway script seems to run fine and creates the table below (from DEBUG logs of org.flywaydb). The SQL is meant to set up the foreign key with the same name as the `@JoinTable` `@ForeignKey` but the validator seems to try and use the Hibernate default of `entity_id` as the foreign key name.

```sql
create TABLE `agent_descriptions` (
    `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `short_description` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
    `long_description` varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
    `fk_agent_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Agent_Description_To_Agent` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_agent_id`) REFERENCES `agents` (`id`),
    KEY `FK_Agent_ID` (`fk_agent_id`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

The error I get from the Hibernate schema validator on startup is:

```
 Schema-validation: missing column [agent_id] in table [agent_descriptions]
```

I am guessing I need to do something to have the validator use the JPA annotation `@JoinTable(foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_agent_id"))` for the foreign key validation or is this a limitation of the DLL `validate` schema option?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`foreignKey` defines the name of the foreign key constraint, not the name of the column.

Your column is still named `agent_id` if it's using the default for Hibernate ORM and so your Flyway script needs to be fixed this way:

```
`agent_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. I did a bit of digging (looked at source) and just overlooked you can set the cloumn name in @JoinColumn...If you just add that you can add @JoinColumn(name="fk_agent_id", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="FK_foreignKeyName") I can verify your answer :)